# Data-Transer increased after migrating to EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, networking, amazon-eks, akamai

Recently, I migrated one of my applications to EKS. Which was before on normal nginx-EC2 setup.

Frontend is in **NextJS** and backend is in **nodejs** and I am using **akamai** for caching for both frontend and backend. Before migrating to EKS the data-transfer was about 2 TB per day but after the migration it went to 5 TB. This data transfer is from akamai to user

Configuration for the app is same. Don't know how to pin-point root cause.

I was going through the **Kubeshark** and found there are only two requests appearing more and more one for `kube-dns` and other for `prometheus-coredns`. Is prometheus-coredns causing this?

Will appreciate help in troubleshooting.

I tried reducing the frontend application replicas after which data-transfer decreased little bit. Don't know how.